# What does first.user = current_user mean/do and why is it working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, nested-forms

To start, I have 3 Models:

```
Location has_many :products
User has_many :products
Products belongs_to :user, :location
```

Now i have a nested form:

```
<%= nested_form_for @location do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
.............
<% f.fields_for :products do |product| %>
```

I was trying to find the right way to get my current_user association to work and suddenly out of pure chance found the right answer in this question, [Nil foreign key in a nested form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804854/nil-foreign-key-in-a-nested-form).

I put this piece of simple code in my controller and it finally gave my products to the current user_id:

```
@location.products.first.user = current_user
```

full -

```
def create
    @location = Location.new(params[:location])
    @location.products.first.user = current_user
end
```

My end goal was accomplished. Users have their own products created at the specific location. Only thing i don't understand is why `first.user = current_user` works and something simple like `location = @location.current_user.products.build` doesn't. Could someone give me a great explanation on whats going on here and what the former means? Is this OK to have or is their a safer/better way?

Thank you, i do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During this statement

```
@location.products.first.user = current_user
```

Rails, by default, assigns the id of the current_user to the left hand side. It is made possible by the internal call to the [to_param](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param). You can even override that method to return something else, even random stuff, but it wont be helpful :)

regarding the `@location.current_user.products.build`,
  this will not work because location and user are not related, if you want to make this work, you can do it by building a product in the new method and passing the current user id as a parameter to the method.

```
def new
  @location = Location.new
  @location.products.build
  respond_to do|format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

UPDATE: I accept tumtu's comment, it is not advisable to put the user id as a hidden element.

Comment: Using the user_id in the views is serious security flaw, user_id should be added to `attr_protected` list.

Comment: @Felix the def new method you placed down just gives me the price fields already added, which i was figuring out how to do and which i give you thanks for but it still didn't assign the correct user_id.

Comment: Yes that's true...it just builds a blank product that belongs to the location...in order to set it, you can set it like you did or you can create a before_filter that gets executed only for the create action that assigns the user_id.If you are going to use the latter case, you don't have use the new method in the create action.You can directly assign the params to the @location.if this comment is not clear, I ll update my answer in a few mins...:)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to define `current_user` is

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base  
  protect_from_forgery  
  helper_method :current_user  

private  
  def current_user  
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]  
  end  
end
```

so `current_user` is defined inside `ApplicationController` class
whenever you trying to do

```
@location = Location.new(params[:location])
@location.current_user
```

you're trying to call method defined in other class as a method of the `Location` instance

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?